# How to enable zero trust mode in fingerprintjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fingerprintjs

I am using `fingerprintjs` in my react project. I want to enable `zero trust mode`. I have read docs https://dev.fingerprint.com/docs/zero-trust-mode
But I can't find info to implement in react project. Please Help me with some solutions.

Code I tried:

```
import { useVisitorData } from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-pro-react';
const { data, getData } = useVisitorData({ tag: "sub" });
 useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.visitorId) {
      console.log(data?.visitorId)
    }
  }, [data?.visitorId])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero trust mode functionality must be enabled by the Fingerprint support team for the specific subscription/application. There are no additional settings required in the client side configuration (either in the default vanilla JS/TS agent or any provided library).